# Scala - Extending a reference type without subclassing it

Tags: java, scala

I have a Java class that I would like to subclass.  The subclass is to add convenience methods only - it could all be done using external methods, because I only look at the public fields, and I don't modify anything.

If the base class was a value type, I'd use value wrappers - `extends AnyVal`.  But the base class is a Java reference type.  Is there any better way to subclass it other than extending it?

Comment: What's the difference?  Aren't all classes in Scala Java reference types?  They all extend java.lang.Object. (This is a serious question, btw.  I really don't understand what you are trying to do.)

Comment: If you don't want to extend it, you could use the *Pimp My Library* pattern.

Comment: Note that you can use value classes to wrap non-value types—see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26869791/334519) for a demonstration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To address your second paragraph specifically, the type you wrap with a value class *can* be a reference type and you still avoid the extra object allocation that would normally be involved in the wrapping. For example, if you've got these implicit classes:

```
implicit class MyInt(val underlying: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def inc: Int = underlying + 1
}

implicit class MyString(val underlying: String) extends AnyVal {
  def firstChar: Char = underlying.charAt(0)
}

implicit class MyNonValueClassString(val underlying: String) {
  def firstCharNonValueClass: Char = underlying.charAt(0)
}
```

And this code that uses them:

```
println(42.inc)
println("hello".firstChar)
println("hello".firstCharNonValueClass)
```

You can compile with `-Xprint:flatten` to see the desugared version (reformatted here for clarity):

```
scala.this.Predef.println(
  scala.Int.box(Demo$MyInt.this.inc$extension(Demo.this.MyInt(42)))
);

scala.this.Predef.println(
  scala.Char.box(
    Demo$MyString.this.firstChar$extension(Demo.this.MyString("hello"))
  )
);

scala.this.Predef.println(
  scala.Char.box(
    Demo.this.MyNonValueClassString("hello").firstCharNonValueClass()
  )
);
```

As you can see, the `firstChar` call doesn't involve a new object.

Answer (score 2):

**Favor composition over inheritance.**

So in your case the best way is probably to create a class having the Java class as an attribute. Then you can simply delegate the methods of this objects and add your own:

```
class MyClass(jo: JavaObject) {
    def delegateMethod() = jo.method()
    def newMethod() = // ...
}
```